# Preventing a dialog from closing in the button's click event handler

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms

I have a dialog that I show with `<class>.ShowDialog()`. It has an OK button and a Cancel button; the OK button also has an event handler.

I want to do some input validation in the event handler and, if it fails, notify the user with a message box and prevent the dialog from closing. I don't know how to do the last part (preventing the close).

Answer (score 55, accepted):

***Given that you've specified you want a pop error dialog***, one way of doing this is to move your validation into a [`Form.OnFormClosing`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.onformclosing?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) event handler. In this example the form close is aborted if the user answers yes to the question in the dialog.

```
private void Form1_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
   // Determine if text has changed in the textbox by comparing to original text.
   if (textBox1.Text != strMyOriginalText)
   {
      // Display a MsgBox asking the user to save changes or abort.
      if(MessageBox.Show("Do you want to save changes to your text?", "My Application",
         MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) ==  DialogResult.Yes)
      {
         // Cancel the Closing event from closing the form.
         e.Cancel = true;
         // Call method to save file...
      }
   }
}
```

By setting `e.Cancel = true` you will prevent the form from closing.

**However, it would be a better design/user experience to display the validation errors inline** (via highlighting the offending fields in some way, displaying tooltips, etc.) **and prevent the user from selecting the OK button in the first place.**

Answer (score 160):

You can cancel closing by setting the Form's `DialogResult` to `DialogResult.None`.

An example where button1 is the AcceptButton:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  if (!validate())
     this.DialogResult = DialogResult.None;
}
```

When the user clicks button1 and the validate method returns false, the form will not be closed.

Comment: Wouldn't it also be necessary to then add `else DialogResult = DialogResult.OK` so that when they fix their errors and hit OK the next time that the Dialog Result is then set properly?

Comment: Because the AcceptButton is button1, the DialogResult is always set to DialogResult.OK when it is clicked.

Answer (score 17):

Don't use the FormClosing event for this, you'll want to allow the user to dismiss the dialog with either Cancel or clicking the X.  Simply implement the OK button's Click event handler and don't close until you are happy:

```
private void btnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  if (ValidateControls())
    this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
}
```

Where "ValidateControls" is your validation logic.  Return false if there's something wrong.

Comment: One minor detail - this does assume you haven't specified DialogResult : OK as part of the design-time setup of the OK button.

Comment: Then you do the inverse, setting it to None when validation fails.

Comment: while the other answers are helpful, ,this is the first one to answer  question as asked

Comment: I was looking for a way to stop an OK action completing. The information in this answer allowed me to figure that out for myself.

Answer (score 3):

You can catch FormClosing an there force the form to remain opened.
use the Cancel property of the event argument object for that.

```
e.Cancel = true;
```

and it should stop your form from closing.

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't directly answer your question (other already have), but from a usability point of view, I would prefer the offending button be disabled while the input is not valid.

Comment: Well, yes, I thought of that but when a particular input contains an invalid value it's clearly marked with a red background.. I think it's enough even if disabling the button is trivial to implement, I guess, and no down sides to do it

Comment: The problem with this approach is that for more complicated forms it might not be obvious to the user what they need to do in order to enable the button again. This sort of on-the-fly validation would work better in conjunction with other things, such as ErrorProviders etc.

Answer (score 3):

Use this code:

```
private void btnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  if (ValidateControls())
    this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
}
```

The problem of it is that the user has to clic two times the buttons for closing the forms;

Answer (score 1):

Just add one line in the event function

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) 
             {
                this->DialogResult = System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::None;
             }
```

Comment: the dialogueResult will need to be restored once the user has corrected the error?

Answer (score 0):

I wish I had time to find a better example, but you would be much better off using the existing windows forms validation techniques to do this.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229603.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
void SaveInfo()
{
blnCanCloseForm = false;
Vosol[] vs = getAdd2DBVosol();
if (DGError.RowCount > 0)
return;

Thread myThread = new Thread(() =>
{
this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate {
    picLoad.Visible = true;
    lblProcces.Text = "Saving ...";
});
int intError = setAdd2DBVsosol(vs);
Action action = (() =>
{
    if (intError > 0)
    {
        objVosolError = objVosolError.Where(c => c != null).ToArray();
        DGError.DataSource = objVosolError;// dtErrorDup.DefaultView;
        DGError.Refresh();
        DGError.Show();
        lblMSG.Text = "Check Errors...";
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Saved All Records...");
        blnCanCloseForm = true;
        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
        this.Close();
    }

});
this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate {
    picLoad.Visible = false;
    lblProcces.Text = "";
});
this.BeginInvoke(action);
});
myThread.Start();
}

void frmExcellImportInfo_FormClosing(object s, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (!blnCanCloseForm)
        e.Cancel = true;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can probably check the form before the users hits the OK button.  If that's not an option, then open a message box saying something is wrong and re-open the form with the previous state.

Comment: You can probably check the form before the users hits the OK button --> When? I can only check when they try to "submit" (borrowing the web's terminology) it, otherwise it will be invalid simply because the user hasn't had a chance to fill it in first. Your second suggestion is fairly difficult to implement; I was hoping for something simpler (or a different way to do what I'm trying to do)