# Detecting when the user is trying to close a form with OK or Cancel?

Tags: c#

This sounds like it should have a simple solution but I can't work it out.

I have a c# form and a `FormClosing` event handler:

```
private void DrawBorderForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    _dCornerRadius = 0.0;
    bool bIsDouble = false;

    try
    {
        bIsDouble = Double.TryParse(textBoxRadius.Text, out _dCornerRadius);
    }
    catch
    {
        bIsDouble = false;
    }

    if (!bIsDouble || _dCornerRadius < 0.0 || _dCornerRadius > 100.0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please input a radius value of 0 to 100!");
        e.Cancel = true;

        return;
    }
}
```

It validates some of the text values and suppressing closing the form if the values are not **OK**.

The problem is that this handler is firing for both **OK** and **Cancel** and **Close**. I don't need to validate if they Cancel or Close. Just if they click OK and therefore want to close the form.

Comment: From a UX perspective, the "OK" button should not be clickable so long as the data is invalid. But for your particular purpose, you should handle the OK button's clicked event instead of the form closing event.

Comment: Then just use a flag inside `OK`

Comment: Well, it would help seeing the code that closes this Form. You should set a variable, let's call it "Cancel", when the user has pressed the Cancel button, before you actually close the form. Then in FormClosing check that variable and discard all data if it is set to true.

Comment: Are you displaying the form with ShowDialog? if so you can check the result of ShowDialog method.

Comment: @GuillaumeCR I have added an answer where I use the OK handler. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can analyze `this.DialogResult`, this is already set when the form closing event is fired

Comment: Thank you. However I have adjusted it based on the comments to use the OK click handler.

Comment: I will accept your answer because it is more direct to the question as a resolution. But I have adopted my own answer as the way forward.

Answer (score 0):

I found this question that answers it:

[Preventing a dialog from closing in the button's click event handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2499644/preventing-a-dialog-from-closing-in-the-buttons-click-event-handler)

```
private void btnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _dCornerRadius = 0.0;
    bool bIsDouble = false;

    bIsDouble = Double.TryParse(textBoxRadius.Text, out _dCornerRadius);

    if (!bIsDouble || _dCornerRadius < 0.0 || _dCornerRadius > 100.0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please input a radius value of 0 to 100!");
        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.None;
    }
}
```