# Detecting which button was clicked when closing a winform?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, formclosing

I have this event handler in my winform:

```
private void SaveToDXF_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    // Make sure the user has selected at-least one layer
    if (listBoxLayers.SelectedItems.Count == 0)
    {
        _AcAp.Application.ShowAlertDialog("Please select one or more layers.");
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

Originally I was using the **OK** button click handler but I quickly found out that there did not seem to be a way to cancel out of actually closing the form. Then I read on SO a suggestion to use [`FormClosing`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2499691/2287576). This works fine but ...

If the user closing the form by pressing the **Cancel** button this event still fires. That makes sense. But I only want to perform this validation check and cancel closing the form if they click the **OK** button.

How do we do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you can check the `this.DialogResult` in the closing handler: it will be different depending which button was clicked (whatever you set as the `DialogResult` in the properties grid).

e.g. "don't do the check if they are cancelling" could be like

```
if (this.DialogResult != DialogResult.Cancel && listBoxLayers.SelectedItems.Count == 0)
```

If you have more checks to do it might be simple to just "if cancelling then return" as the event handler first line